# Storage of database credentials in php.ini or a php file (ex. database_connection.php)?

Tags: php, mysql

Is one preferred over another?

And what would be php.ini equivalent syntax to connect to a database the same way this php script does?

#### database_connection.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
?>
```

Comment: I'd never set the default credentials in php.ini, but if you have a dedicated box you could do it with [simply settings the default values](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent syntax would be:

```
$conn = mysql_connect() or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
```

There are no required parameters. If you do not provide any, the defaults from `php.ini` are used.